# fatal error C1016: #if[n]def expected an identifier

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

```
// File: Lab13Frac.h

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#ifndef "Lab13Frac.h"
#define "Lab13Frac.h"

// prototpes

#endif
```

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: Type in 4 spaces before each line of code.

Comment: You format code by selecting it, then clicking the "101010" button.

Comment: Which inserts 4 spaces before each line, formatting it at code. Also, put *everything* inside the header guards, including includes. And **don't use `using namespace`!** Especially in a header.

Answer (score 7):

The identifier should not be in quotes. Also, it should be in all caps by convention.

```
// File: Lab13Frac.h

#ifndef LAB13FRAC_H
#define LAB13FRAC_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
// The above line is not recommended in header files
// because it may cause namespace collisions.
// See http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/coding-standards.html#faq-27.5

// Prototypes

#endif
```

Comment: Depending on coding style, it's also possible to write (for example) `#ifndef _LAB13FRAC_H_ ... ` and sometimes `#endif // _LAB13FRAC_H_`

Comment: @Kotti: Except those identifiers are reserved for the compiler. (Any name starting with an underscore followed by another underscore or capital letter are reserved.)

Comment: @GMan Know about the double underscore, but it's the first time when I've heard about `_X....` being reserved. Could you point to some docs to read?

Comment: @Kotti, See C++0X FCD 17.6.3.3.2.1:
Certain sets of names and function signatures are always reserved to the implementation:
— Each name that contains a double underscore _ _ or begins with an underscore followed by an uppercase
letter (2.12) is reserved to the implementation for any use.
— Each name that begins with an underscore is reserved to the implementation for use as a name in the
global namespace.

Comment: @Kotti: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier/228797#228797

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do that

```
// File: Lab13Frac.h
#ifndef LAB13FRAC_H
#define LAB13FRAC_H

#include <iostream>

using namespace std; //You shouldn't do this anyway...

// prototpes
#endif //LAB13FRAC_H
```

You can't use a string as an identifier, use a literal as if it is a variable name.
Also, you should put a comment next to `#endif` to tell who reads what you are `#endif`ing